# Timing interval between GET and POST request in Node/Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I am building a quiz website using Node/Express.

How do I ensure that users submit quiz within a specified period of time without using client-side javascript? That is, if the quiz takes 10 minutes, submission afterwards should marked as too late.

Both GET and POST requests are to the same url

Answer (score 2):

Dépends on the level of security and bad-connectivity-proofness you want, but what I would do is start a timer server-side when the quizz is served to the client, and reject it if the answer is submitted after a given period (10mn plus a little margin).

And to keep the client aware, you could code a client-side timer that would use as start time a value set directly in the client html by the server when serving the page.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Yes. I get that. I'd just appreciate sample code to illustrate the fact because I don't know how the POST request handler can get the time variable from the GET request handler

Comment: I won't post code because some guy did it in the answer below, but I would simply read the submit time server-side. Because if you read it from a form sent by the client, you take the risk that the user modifies the form input or messes with the time settings of his PC.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question to solve in a evaluations app.

Here is the way I save a new date allowing to later check on server if the time is bigger than my limit when answering:

**Client code:**

```
startEvaluation: function (data) {
        return $http.put(startUrl + '/' + data._id,data);
      },
```

**Server code:**

```
exports.startEvaluation = function (req, res) {
  if(req.body.status==="NEW")req.body.status="STARTED";
  req.body.started=Date.now();
    Evaluation.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.body._id}, req.body, {upsert:true , new: true }, function(err, evaluation)
    {
       if (err) {
            return handleError(res, err);
         }
         if (!evaluation) {
            return res.send(404);
         }
    });
};
```

Hope it helps

**EDIT:**

As you said are the same urls, you can use the parameter (like new for example). This way, if you answer with a NEW condition, you just call the begin  method:

```
exports.answer = function (req, res) {
  if(req.body.status==="NEW")
  {
    req.body.status="STARTED";
    req.body.started=Date.now();
  }
  else
  {
    //Process answer here and compare another Date.now() with the stored date, and your time limit to answer
    console.log("answer");
  }

    Evaluation.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.body._id}, req.body, {upsert:true , new: true }, function(err, evaluation)
    {
       if (err) {
            return handleError(res, err);
         }
         if (!evaluation) {
            return res.send(404);
         }
        //here is the updated evaluation with the started value.
        return res.json(200, evaluations);

    });
};
```

**The method on the client:**

```
 $scope.saveAnswer = function ()
            {

                if($rootScope.evaluation.status==="NEW")
                {
                    evaluationService.startEvaluation($rootScope.evaluation);
                }
                else
                {
                  //Your answer treatment
                } 

}
```

> Anyway, a little improve on server could be done checking the test
>   must be started to allow answering.

**EDIT**

> Here is the code for the server to control the status of the
>   evaluation/quiz from the backside. This allows you to mark as
>   "outdated" the evaluations the user did not finish during the allowed
>   20 mins after the beginning of the quiz. Note that a `setTimeout` is
>   done to leave the task on server side, waiting to reach the max time
>   configured (20 mins in example)

```
function marcarNoTerminada(id, body) {      
         //later you can check the status to filter answers given after limit hour
         body.status="NOT FINISHED";
         Evaluation.findOneAndUpdate({_id: id}, body, {upsert:true , new: true }, function(err, evaluation)
    {
       console.log("Evaluacion sin finalizar");
    });
}

exports.startEvaluation = function (req, res) {
  if(req.body.status==="NEW")req.body.status="STARTED";
  req.body.started=Date.now();
  req.body.validEnd= new Date(req.body.started+(60000*20));

    var theTimer = setTimeout(function(){marcarNoTerminada(req.body._id, req.body);}, 60000*20); 
    Evaluation.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.body._id}, req.body, {upsert:true , new: true }, function(err, evaluation)
    {
       if (err) {
            return handleError(res, err);
         }
         if (!evaluation) {
            return res.send(404);
         }

        return res.json(200, evaluation);
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you Alejandro. Is the NEW parameter default to bodyParser

Comment: U welcome!. I just create the parameter on body when the user views the first screen on the quiz (my limitation is only 20 minutes - 20 answers, then I only check before the first one). Thay says me when the user has read rules and started the quiz. After that, on every answer, I check if the user has passed the limit. Anyway, you can do it with a particular timer for every answer but it should be a little improve.

Comment: I'm sorry.  I meant to ask about request.body.STATUS